# ASP.Net C# Reminder Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, reminders

I am about the start developing a reminder application using any below 
ASP.Net C# 4.0 web forms / ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Razor Views / Console Application 
SQL Server 2008 / Entity FrameWork 4.1

I have already created reminder forms, where user will create their reminders
with time and date when they want to be reminded.

Now my program should look-In database and check for any active reminder list and send a Email reminder.

This is what I thought:

1. Write a console program
2. That is scheduled to Run every minute on server
3. This program will check the Reminders Table to find all active
4. Reminder for that minute
5. And Compose Email and send it out.

But I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.
Any suggestions / ideas are greatly appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of this application will most likely be a windows service.  The service runs on a timer that will make the necessary data requests.  Then send the email and may fire off toaster, or app windows to alert the user when items are found.

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation or some sort of reference program. I am not familiar with how to write a windows Service.

Comment: @HaBo Here's a link to a Windows Service tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: WCF is a good call.  Lots of documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784
If you want to go with a straight service you can start here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @MatthewVines How can WCF do same job as Windows Service. which one is better for this job? If WCF is better than I prefer working on it.

Comment: @HaBo - that's a tricky question, if this is just a piece of a much larger service oriented product.  I would probably pitch WCF as a better way to go.  However, if this is all that needs to be done.  I would probably just stick with a Windows Service.

Comment: Got you thanks, I am working on windows Service now. Will update here, how it went.

Comment: I would say Windows Service is the right thing for your scenario. Pointing you to WCF seems to me like hitting a very small problem with a very huge hammer. Besides you would need some secondary mechanism to trigger your wcf-service (like a scheduled task or a windows service), so using wcf alone would not solve your problem.

Comment: @MatthewVines I got this worked with Windows service. But a new problem with Time Zones. I am stuck with this  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11677813/942855

Answer (score 0):

Use CRON triggers instead of polling.  Quartz.NET use CRON and work well.  Lots of tutorials and download 
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html