# Find UTC Time for ALL USA TimeZone for below Times using C#.net

Tags: c#, utc, localtime

How can i find UTC time for all these TimeZone for all these hours

- 8 Am (in UTC for all USA Time Zones)
- 5 PM (in UTC for all USA Time Zones)
- 10 PM (in UTC for all USA Time Zones)

**USA Time Zones**

1. Hawaii Time
2. Alaska Time
3. Pacific Time
4. Mountain Time
5. Central Time
6. Eastern Time

I need to find it using C#.net

**More Details:**
For all who are curious what am I doing with these times.
I have to run a scheduled job at these times
8AM, 5PM and 10PM every day
And this time should be user local time.
So if I find all UTC time for 6 zones
I though I can run my scheduled job at all those UTC times.
That will be **6 zones x 3 times(8,5,10) = 18 times I will run my batch** 
Hope this approach make sense to you.

Thanks

Comment: @PeterRitchie Never worked with TimeZones. so, yes you can consider this as a Kindergarten Home Work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For help converting between time zones, check out this article.
http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/24/timezone-vs-timezoneinfo-in-net/

If you just want to check if right now is a certain time in utc

`DateTime.UtcNow.Hour` will probably be pretty helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was the solution for me.